# Creating puzzle animation in WP7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am creating a puzzle app for kids, in that puzzle contains images of fruits, here the images of fruits will be splited  in to  3 or more pieces. what i need is, i need to drag this piece in to a specific area and if the position where i placed the image piece is correct   means the image must need to attach there otherwise the image will need to move back to its original position automatically. Please give me a initial guide line to start this app. I am new to this Silverlight game development and i dnt know where to start this proj. Pls help me...

Comment: For a single screen game like this, i would definitely recommend **Silverlight** not XNA. You can get most of the game done using Blend. There is an almost exact copy of your game given as an example in the tutorial videos by rob and andy on channel nine, available [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/egibson/windows-phone-7-jump-start-session-2-of-12-building-a-silverlight-application-part-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Wp7 you can develop in silverlight or XNA.  As this is a game you might find XNA an easier place to start from.  Please find a tutorial on creating a tic-tac-toe game in the link below.  IMHO your game concept sounds like it would have a similar layout and similar logic (you are placing pieces on a board) so perhaps if you follow this tutorial you will get some ideas:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/windows-phone-7-game-development/

Comment: Cheers, good luck with the game